# dir tag pushing content to the side in mobile

Tags: html, css

I'm using dir tags to take content that is side by side in desktop to be stacked (right over left) in mobile. But it seems to be pushing the text to the side rather than wrapping it underneath the image.

```
<table class="deviceWidth" dir="rtl"  width="100%" 
cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:
 collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; ">

  <tr>
    <td width="50%" dir="ltr" align="right" class="full">
      <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0; padding:0;   margin:0;">
       <a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" alt="" border="0" style="display: block; width:100%; height:auto;" /></a> 
      </p>                  
    </td>
    <td width="50%" dir="ltr" align="left" class="full" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:18px;color:#000000;line-height:18px; padding: 5px;">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.                       
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Along with:

```
 @media only screen and (max-width:620px) {
 table[id=container] .full {
 display:block !important;
 width:100% !important;
 }
```

Everything works fine on desktop, but when I switch to a mobile view the image grows, and the text just gets pushed up into a smaller column on the side and I can't seem to figure out the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Update Html**

**Live Demo Fiddle**  [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/819dvLe5/)  And resize output and then check it in fiddle.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:620px) {
 table[id=container] .full {
 display:block !important;
 width:100% !important;
 }
```

```html
<table class="deviceWidth" dir="rtl"  width="100%" 
cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:
 collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; ">

  <tr>
    <td width="50%" dir="ltr" align="right" class="full" style="position:relative">
      <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0; padding:0;   margin:0; position:absolute;top:0;right:0;">
       <a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" alt="" border="0" style="display: block; width:100%; height:auto;" /></a> 
      </p>                  
    </td>
    <td width="50%" dir="ltr" align="left" class="full" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:18px;color:#000000;line-height:18px; padding: 5px;">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.                       
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```